# Is there any crossplatform GUI for Ruby that is easy to install on Mac OS?

Tags: ruby

I have some ruby scripts for end users that will be nice to have some GUI. Some of users use Windows, some Mac OS X (Snow Leopard, Lion). So i need some kind of cross-platform GUI that my users can easily install. For Windows where is built-in Tk and a number of gems that can be installed as easy as `gem install wxRuby`. But on MacOS i have some problems:

- No built-in Tk due to 64-it nature of Snow Leopard+ and no **easy** way to install it.
- qtRuby4 gem does not exist for Mac OS X at all.
- gtk2 gem is native and fails to build on Mac OS X Snow Leopard+
- wxruby gem install but will not work on 64-bit Snow Leopard+, scripts need to be executed manually in 32-bit mode.

Maybe someone can suggest some distribution / way to install GUI toolkit for ruby that will be **easy to install** for end users for both Windows and Mac OS X Snow Leopard / Lion? Or the wxRuby is the only way and i need to somehow make sure that end users execute scripts in 32-bit mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for now it seems that the easiest way will be to use Ruby-GNOME2. The instruction to configure ruby for OSX will be to install macports via standard `.dmg` installer and execute one command:

```
sudo -s "port selfupdate; port install ruby; gem install gtk2"
```

Of course installing something is not very user-friendly, but manual tinkering with 32-bit / 64-bit interpreter execution for wxRuby afraids me more. That will require either to modify end user system or to add some kind of bootstrapper into **each** script so it will check if executed on 64-bit macos and in such case relaunch itself in 32-bit interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/) may fit the bill.

Comment: As far as i know it is **very** simple and author has dropped it's support years ago.

Comment: Fair enough - how about [MonkeyBars](http://monkeybars.org/)? Again, I haven't used it, and this time I don't know much about Java Swing and its cross-platform-ness.

Comment: Monkeybars are `jruby`-based. My main goal is to minimize end users actions assuming they already have ruby installed on their Windows or Mac OS X computer. Running something like `gem install somegui` is **ok** i think. But installing java, jruby, configuring something etc... i don't think it will be user-friendly ^_^

Comment: @Eye of Hell: It's quite simple but depending on the app might be enough. The original author has dropped support for it, but people picked it up and are working on it again. There's also an alternative version called "Green Shoes" which is a pure Ruby gem and doesn't come with its own Ruby environment like (Red) Shoes does.

Comment: Shoes is still being actively developed (just by other people since _why's left): http://blog.shoesrb.com/ Commit list: https://github.com/shoes/shoes/commits/develop

Comment: @Mchl: Mac support for updated shoes is **only** 10.6 64-bit :). It's same as wxRuby 32-bi restriction being put aother way :(

Comment: Bad luck. I suppose Shoes is a no go then until they release a Ruby only version.

Answer (score 0):

There was a Ruby GUI survey in 2008, which would need an update. Maybe it's still interesting though:

http://www.pressure.to/ruby_gui_survey/

IMHO from your list your best bet is wxRuby, sans the 32-bit limitation. An alternative way would be to wrap up your application as a lightweight web app using something like Sinatra, starting a server on localhost and telling the user where to go in the browser. That is if doing GUIs in JavaScript is your thing.

Comment: It's outdated. Since 2008 the top1, shoes, was dropped by author and top2, ruby-gnome2 is no longer compiles under Snow Leopard and Lion :(.

Comment: I know, I said it would need an update, I just wasn't sure if you were aware of it at all. And as I said in my other comment, Shoes is still alive, the main version is supported by a group of volunteers and my pal Satoshi has an alternative version called "Green Shoes": https://github.com/ashbb/green_shoes

Comment: Unfortunately, green shoes is based on ruby-gtk2, and as i mentioned above ruby-gtk2 will not build on OSX 10.6 and later.